# Overlay specification introduces offset in figures placement in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, horizontal-alignment, overlays

I'm placing some figures in my beamer slides, such as:

```
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{XXX}
\begin{block}{XXX}
    \begin{columns}[t,onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}[]{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{figure}[ht]
                \raggedleft
                \includegraphics<1>[width=0.9\columnwidth]{xx1-mod.png}
                \includegraphics<2>[width=0.9\columnwidth]{xx2-mod.png}
                \includegraphics<3>[width=0.9\columnwidth]{xx3-mod.png}
                \pause
            \end{figure}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
```

I've noted that a small offset is introduced at the right side of the figures, progressively reducing as until disappearing such as only the last figure is correctly right-aligned. Is this expected? How can I get rid of it?

Comment: What's the purpose of `figure`? Leave it out. If you add a blank line between the images, you are safe from drifting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{XXX}
\begin{block}{XXX}
    \begin{columns}[t,onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}[]{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{figure}[ht]
                \raggedleft
                \includegraphics<1>[width=0.9\columnwidth]{example-image-a}%
                \includegraphics<2>[width=0.9\columnwidth]{example-image-b}%
                \includegraphics<3>[width=0.9\columnwidth]{example-image-c}%
                \pause
            \end{figure}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{block}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

only one image was in each overlay but you were adding one inter-word space into each overlay whether or not the image was included. Commenting out with `%` makes all three images come at the same place.